# Logstash-forwarder TLS handshake error - Server selected unsupported protocol version 301

Tags: windows, ssl-certificate, tls

I have the problem below just with windows. I tried with linux and it works fine.

When I run:

```
.\logstash-forwarder-master.exe -config .\logstash-forwarder2.conf
```

With logstash-forwarder2.conf:

```
{
  "network": {
  "servers": [ "10.0.1.136:5034" ],
  "ssl key": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\logstash-forwarder-master\\certs\\logstash-forwarder.key",
  "ssl certificate": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\logstash-forwarder-master\\certs\\logstash-forwarder.crt",
  "ssl ca": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\logstash-forwarder-master\\certs\\logstash-forwarder.crt",

   "timeout": 15
},

"files": [
  {
      "paths": [ 
      "C: \\logs\\example.log"
      ]
  }
 ]
}
```

I receive the following error:

```
Failed to tls handshake with 10.0.1.136 tls: Server selected unsupported protocol version 301
```

Nevertheless when I run:

```
C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin\openssl.exe s_client -showcerts -connect 10.0.1.136:5034
```

I receive:

```
Loading 'screen' into random state - done
CONNECTED(00000118)
depth=0 C = AU, ST = Some-State, O = Internet Widgits Pty Ltd
verify error:num=18:self signed certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 C = AU, ST = Some-State, O = Internet Widgits Pty Ltd
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
0 s:/C=AU/ST=Some-State/O=Internet Widgits Pty Ltd
  i:/C=AU/ST=Some-State/O=Internet Widgits Pty Ltd
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
 omitted
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
---
Server certificate
subject=/C=AU/ST=Some-State/O=Internet Widgits Pty Ltd
issuer=/C=AU/ST=Some-State/O=Internet Widgits Pty Ltd
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 1012 bytes and written 621 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is RC4-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : RC4-SHA
    Session-ID: 54B3A8D9594F45F1562FA16A462766CE72918E11A2E92EC1429FFD721F6637E5
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: 7C59315873B89D1C8DE678BECDF11F4E458A6B987BB2C8A55548207BD95121156889FC14F1247F38DB1CD0F9D794D050
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1421060929
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 18 (self signed certificate)
---
```

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind,

I uninstalled the logstash-forwarder client and installed [another logstash-forwarder client](http://www.elasticsearch.org/overview/logstash/download/)

I got this error instead:

```
Failed to tls handshake with 10.0.1.136:5034 tls: either ServerName or InsecureSkipVerify must be specified in the tls.Config
```

and I found the solution of this [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/golang-dev/oxCbyIjUEE0/rs14DA1a82EJ)

Adding this line

```
tlsconfig.InsecureSkipVerify = true
```

And now it works fine